# Apache Flink Dynamically setting JVM_OPT env.java.opts

Tags: apache-flink

Is it possible to set the custom JVM Options `env.java.opts` when submitting a job without specifying it in the `conf/flink-conf.yaml` file?

The reason I am asking is I want to use some custom variables in my log4j. I am also running my job on YARN.

I have tried the following command using the CLI and it strips everything off from the `=` sign onwards

```
$ flink run -m yarn-cluster -yn 2 -yst -yD env.java.opts="-DappName=myapp -DcId=mycId"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment this is not possible due to the way Flink parses the dynamic properties. Flink assumes that dynamic properties have the form `-D<KEY>=<VALUE>` and that `<VALUE>` does not contain any `=` which is clearly wrong. Thus, for the moment you have to specify the `env.java.opts` via `flink-conf.yaml`.

I've opened a [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-6581) to fix this problem.

#### Update

The problem has been fixed for Flink >= 1.3.0 and >= 1.2.2.

Comment: It has been fixed

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution which I tried was passing the configuration parameters in application.properties as arguments like below,

```
~/flink/bin/flink run app.jar --Brokers=Broker1:9093 --TopicName=some-topic
```

Also you can also pass in the parameters as a properties file,

```
~/flink/bin/flink run app.jar -Dspring.config.name=<full-path>/application.properties
```